# Get admin quote details using adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data

Tags: php

I want to set shipping price for orders created in admin based on products in cart, how to get the quote items using `adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data`?

Answer (score 0):

To: **adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data** but make sure you add this into the `<adminhtml>` node in your `config.xml`.

Once in your Observer.php, you can remove the items you wish, I would instead try to hook to a quote event also in the `<adminhtml>` node and then remove the item at a quote level if possible.

To add an item to the quote:

```
$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($eventArgs));
$quote->save();
```

To remove an item from the quote:

```
$quote->removeItem($item->getItemId())->save();
```

Then you can have magento create the admin order:

```
$adminSalesOrderCreate = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/sales_order_create');
$adminSalesOrderCreate->setQuote($quote)->save();
```